# font-face Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css-font-face

Estou com um problema de carregamento em minhas fontes no IE. Demora cerca de 1 minuto pra serem carregadas. Alguém mais passa ou já passou por isso?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'yanone_regular';
src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-regular-webfont.svg#yanone_kaffeesatzregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'yanone_bold';
src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-bold-webfont.svg#yanone_kaffeesatzbold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'yanone_light';
src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.eot');
src: url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.svg#yanone_kaffeesatzlight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Comment: A font esta local? Ou você esta pegando ela de fora?

Comment: To usando a técnica do font-face. Logo elas estão no meu servidor.

Comment: @dsantoro Mostra o código que está usando.

Comment: Certifique-se de que esta utilizando os formatos de font que o ie renderiza. *.eot

Comment: Amigo, já pensou em usar Web Font? O Google Fonts tem várias fontes e de graça...

Answer (score 1):

Modifique seu font-face para esse código e veja se funciona:

```
@font-face { 
font-family: MyFont; src: url('myfont.ttf'); 
}
@font-face{ 
font-family: MyFont_IE; src: url('myfont.eot'); 
}
.my_font{ 
font-family: MyFont, MyFont_IE, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}
```

Caso não funcione (Apesar de ter funcionado comigo), dê uma lida aqui:
http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2009/12/webdev/adventures-with-font-face

Ou crie seu próprio fonte neste site:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Comment: As minhas fontes foram criadas nesse fontsquirrel ai mesmo rs.

Comment: Sim, substituiu pelas que passei agora?